# Changing the log level for a running Actor system ?

Tags: scala, logging, akka, logback

My `resources/application.conf` looks like the following.

```
akka {
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
}
```

I'm creating an fat jar using `$sbt assembly` that contains this `application.conf` and deploying this jar to run my actors. Now can I change the log level (from DEBUG to INFO) of my program at runtime without brining down my actor system? If yes, how ?

My logback.xml looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <target>System.out</target>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%X{akkaTimestamp} %-5level[%thread] %logger{0} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>logs/myjobs.log</file>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/myjobs.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>5</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd} %X{akkaTimestamp} %-5level[%thread] %logger{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>


    <logger name="akka" level="INFO" />

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 10):

You can set the Akka loglevel using `system.eventStream.setLogLevel()` (within an Actor you would use `context.system` as the starting point).

Comment: I want to change the log level at runtime from outside the program. Is that possible ?

Comment: By the way the documentation http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/logging.html in my opinion is not at all clear that this is possible, so I think your comment is unfair in that respect.

Comment: Ok, I found this option in https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/event-bus.html#default-handlers under the Event Bus ( like more broad and general topic ) directly before the Logging as a next topic .